# What would cause intermittent SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory errors from php PDO mysql on Debian Lenny?

Tags: php, mysql, linux, sockets, pdo

Connections are through localhost, using the mysqld sock file.  These are working 99+% of the time, but under some weird conditions I get the error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

The same pages will work again on the next request.

The only thing I can think of is some kind of strange filesystem error.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out mysql getting restarted would cause this error. :p  And this site won't let you answer your own question right away for some reason.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Well, what do you need to do when the error happens? What's the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Could be a file permission problem on the sock file.

Mine is in /var/run/mysqld and ls -l of it looks like this

```
srwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql 0 May 14 06:28 mysqld.sock
```